# How to access WSO2 API Manager's Store API?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I was reading the WSO2 APIM documentation for their [Store API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/store/index.html). However I can't figure out how to get authenticated with this API.

From what I understand from this page, I need to get a special token via the /token API. But the example shows that they provide some sort of Authentication to get this token and I can't figure out which one it is.

So I guess my problem is:
- How to get an access token for the WSO API Manager's new Store API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to get access([Reference](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/store/index.html#guide)).

**1.Register your oauth application using dynamic client registration API**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @payload.json http://localhost:9763/client-registration/v0.9/register
```

Sample payload:

```
{
    "callbackUrl": "www.google.lk",
    "clientName": "rest_api_store",
    "tokenScope": "Production",
    "owner": "admin",
    "grantType": "password refresh_token",
    "saasApp": true
}
```

Here it uses basic auth.You need to provide base 64 encoded username:password(eg: admin:admin) in the Authrization header.

Sample response.

```
{
    "callBackURL": "www.google.lk",
    "jsonString":
    "{
    "username":"admin",
    "redirect_uris":"www.google.lk",
    "tokenScope":[Ljava.lang.String;@3a73796a,
    "client_name":"admin_rest_api_store",
    "grant_types":"authorization_code password refresh_token iwa:ntlm
    urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer client_credentialsimplicit"
    }",
    "clientName": null,
    "clientId": "HfEl1jJPdg5tbtrxhAwybN05QGoa",
    "clientSecret": "l6c0aoLcWR3fwezHhc7XoGOht5Aa"
}
```

**2.Use the token API to get the oauth access token**

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=apim:subscribe" -H "Authorization: Basic SGZFbDFqSlBkZzV0YnRyeGhBd3liTjA1UUdvYTpsNmMwYW9MY1dSM2Z3ZXpIaGM3WG9HT2h0NUFh" https://127.0.0.1:8243/toke
```

Here basic auth parameter is base 64 encoded clientId:ClientSecret

Now  you have an access token to call store APIs

Comment: This was the information that was missing in the documentation (what to hash and how to hash it). Thanks!